# In powerbi, is it possible to have axis that changes with sliders?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I was asked to create a bar chart in powerbi whose horizontal axis is able to change with the slicers on screen.

The intended horizontal axis is the rank_category field. You must have noticed that the same field is expressed as a measure, rank_category, and a calculated column, rank_cate.

I've put the rank_category measure in the table at the top (last column), and used rank_cate as the horizontal axis in the bar chart on bottom right; in the bottom left bar chart, the horizontal axis is also rank_cate but it's created via a calculated table.

By selecting the items in the slicer, the measure in the table will has its value changed; the bottom left bar chart doesn't change at all, and the bottom right bar chart also changes but the rank_cate field's value doesn't change. It's just the slicer filtering out those who are not in the group.

So my question is, is it possible at all to create a bar chart with an axis whose value will change according to the slicer, like the last column in the table? Apparently bar charts can only take on columns as an axis, not measures, and calculated columns don't change with slicers. But it would be great to know if anyone has a way around this.

Thanks very much. (The 1st image is the report without slicer on; the 2nd is with slicer selection)
[image]
[image]

Comment: May be there is a simple explanation of your case :) Can you please add sample data and then output you need from that set of sample data? This can make things easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks Rabbani. Unfortunately stack doesn't allow me to post the complete file. Maybe I can send it to your personal inbox?

Comment: Do you mean the PBI file? If yes, you can upload in like google drive and share the public link here so that anyone can do some more analysis.